# Acessar variável de dentro de função: problema de escopo?

Tags: javascript

Como faço para acessar a variável `dados` de dentro do `function`? Exemplo abaixo:

```
     var dados; 

     PagSeguroDirectPayment.getBrand({

            cardBin: this.pedidoSoft.numCard,
            success: function(response) {

                 dados = response;
            },
            error: function(response) {},
            complete: function(response) {}
    });

    console.log(dados);
```

Este código está imprimindo `undefined` no console. acredito que seja problema de escopo da variável. A variável que está sendo acessada dentro não é a mesma de fora. Como consigo acessar essa variável de dentro da função?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Não é problema de escopo. O problema é que a função é assíncrona, é um *callback*. Então você atribui `response` a `dados`, mas só depois que o `console.log` já rodou.

Seja lá o que precise fazer com os dados, faça dentro do callback de sucesso. O jeito mais limpo é chamar uma função e passar pra ela os dados. Isso inclusive encapsula a lógica de tratamento dos dados. Assim:

```
// ...
    success: function(response) {
        trataDados(response);
    },
// ...
});

function trataDados(dados) {
    // faz o que for necessário
}
```

Inclusive dá pra simplificar:

```
// ...
    success: trataDados,
    error: function(response) {},
    complete: function(response) {}
});

function trataDados(dados) {
    // faz o que for necessário
}
```

Comment: obrigado, amigo! era isso mesmo!